# date format change in datepicker and calendar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

How to change `2/3/2013` format to `02/03/2013 (dd/mm/yyyy)`?

```
 Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;
            // set selected date into textview.
            searchText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1).append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year).append(" "));
            Log.i("DatePickerDialog","DatePickerDialog");
            dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
            // set selected date into datepicker also.
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
            user.setSearchEntityType("ByDate");
        }       
    };
```

**Current Output:**

```
1/2/2013 
d/m/y
```

**Looking for:**

```
01/02/2013
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {

    int month = monthOfYear + 1;
    String formattedMonth = "" + month;
    String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

    if(month < 10){

        formattedMonth = "0" + month;
    }
    if(dayOfMonth < 10){

        formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
    }
    searchText.setText(formattedDayOfMonth + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) class. Do something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.instance();
cal.set(year, month, day);
CharSequence output = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", cal);
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get the format like dd/mm/yy.

```
int month = monthOfYear + 1;
String formattedMonth = "" + month;
String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;
String formattedYear=String.valueOf(year);

if(month < 10){

   formattedMonth = "0" + month;
}
if(dayOfMonth < 10){

   formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
}

formattedYear=formattedYear.substring(formattedYear.length()-2);
String date=formattedDayOfMonth + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + formattedYear;
mEDDate.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, add the condition as below:

```
 if (month<10)
   month='0'+month;
 if (day<10)
   day='0'+day;
```

Comment: it is showing in this way [ The method parseInt(int) is undefined for the type new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){}]

Comment: i did in same format. it is giving output as 49/51/2013 any thing i ahve change in searchText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1).append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year).append(" "));