# Android format date to MM-DD-YYYY from Datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, date-format

I have a datepicker. My app is pushing a notification. I want to display the date in 01-07-2013 MM-dd-yyyy format. Please check my code below:

```
 //---Button view---
    Button btnOpen = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btEventDone );
    btnOpen.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {  

            String strT = title.getText().toString();
            String strDes = description.getText().toString();

            // check if user did not input anything
            if( strT.isEmpty() || strDes.isEmpty() ){

                Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "You have blank fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
            else{

            //---use the AlarmManager to trigger an alarm---
            AlarmManager alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );                 

            //---get current date and time---
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       

            //---sets the time for the alarm to trigger---
            calendar.set( Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear() );
            calendar.set( Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth() );
            calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth() );                 
            calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.getCurrentHour() );
            calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, time.getCurrentMinute() );
            calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );

            //---PendingIntent to launch activity when the alarm triggers---                    
            Intent i = new Intent( CalendarEvent.this, DisplayNotification.class );

            year = calendar.get( Calendar.YEAR );
            month = calendar.get( Calendar.MONTH );
            day = calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

            hour = calendar.get( Calendar.HOUR );
            minute = calendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE );

            Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "MM-dd-yyyy");
            String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);

            String strTitle = title.getText().toString();
            String strDescription = description.getText().toString();
            strDate = String.valueOf( month ) + "-" + String.valueOf( day ) + "-" + String.valueOf( year );

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(hour>=12){                      
              sb.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" PM");
            }else{
              sb.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" AM");
            }
            String strTime = sb.toString();


            //---assign an ID of 1---
            i.putExtra( "NotifID", notifID ); 
            i.putExtra( "Title", strTitle );
            i.putExtra( "Description", strDescription );
            i.putExtra( "Date", strDate  );
            i.putExtra( "Time", strTime );

            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), notifID, i, 0 );               


            //---sets the alarm to trigger---
            alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent );
            finish();
        }

        }
    }); 

}
```

**AlarmDetails:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarmdetails);  

    //---look up the notification manager service---
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) 
        getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

    title = ( EditText ) findViewById ( R.id.etDetailTitle );
    description = ( EditText ) findViewById ( R.id.etDetailDescription );
    date = ( EditText ) findViewById ( R.id.etDetailDate );
    time = ( EditText ) findViewById ( R.id.etDetailTime );
    done = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.btnAlarmDone );

    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    //---cancel the notification---
    nm.cancel( getIntent().getExtras().getInt( "NotifID" ) ); 


    String strTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Title" );
    String strDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Description" );
    strDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Date" );
    String strTime = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Time" );
    title.setText( strTitle );
    description.setText( strDescription );
    date.setText( strDate );
    time.setText( strTime );


}
```

**DisplayNotification:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//---get the notification ID for the notification; 
// passed in by the NotifyActivity---
int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt( "NotifID" );
String strTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Title" );
String strDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Description" );
String strDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Date" );
String strTime = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Time" );

//---PendingIntent to launch activity if the user selects 
// the notification---
Intent i = new Intent( DisplayNotification.this, AlarmDetails.class );
i.putExtra( "NotifID", notifID );  
i.putExtra( "Title", strTitle );
i.putExtra( "Description", strDescription );
i.putExtra( "Date", strDate );
i.putExtra( "Time", strTime );

PendingIntent detailsIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager )
    getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
Notification notif = new Notification(
    R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
    "iHealthFirst: Notification!",
    System.currentTimeMillis() );

CharSequence from = "iHealthFirst - New Notification";
CharSequence message = "This is your alert, click to view";        
notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

//---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100 ms and
// then vibrate for 500ms---
notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};        
nm.notify( notifID, notif );

//---destroy the activity---
finish();
}
```

My current app only display in this format M-d-yyyy. I have read that we should use SimpleDateFormat, but I don't know how to use it in my app. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check this:

[date format change in datepicker and calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153811/date-format-change-in-datepicker-and-calendar/14153993#14153993#answers)

```
   year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if(month < 10){

        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if(day < 10){

        day  = "0" + day ;
    }
    searchText.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
```

Answer (score 35):

try this

```
int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String strDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: This solution is much elegant.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this might be to simply collect the data and then use String.format:

```
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String dateString = String.format("%02d-%02d-%d", month, day, year);
    ((TextView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.dob)).setText(dateString);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add this code:

```
Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

after

```
year = calendar.get( Calendar.YEAR );
month = calendar.get( Calendar.MONTH );
day = calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

hour = calendar.get( Calendar.HOUR );
minute = calendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
```

So your strDate will be in format you want (MM-dd-yyyy)

Comment: maybe you mean d in strDate = dateFormatter.format(date); not date? thnks

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, Yes, it will be 'd' instead of variable 'date'. I am editing

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, Can you please edit your question with new code? Because this code works perfectly in my apps

Comment: Hi i've added my 2 classes. Thanks.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, you have put the code at wrong place. Place it before you pass the intent from class DisplayNotification.

Comment: Yeah I've done that, I deleted the code from alarmdetails. I put it in the main activity class but it still displays the same.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, After placing that code your value for strDate is being overridden as you have not removed this line: "strDate = String.valueOf( month ) + "-" + String.valueOf( day ) + "-" + String.valueOf( year );". Remove it and check. I thnk problem should be solved

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, Do one thing. Put a debugging point on String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d); and check the value of strDate at that time. So we can get an idea about the source of problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22364/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-shreya-shah)

Comment: The value of date is 3913.

Answer (score 2):

just use this code..

```
 date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                DatePickerDialog dateDlg = new DatePickerDialog(New_Quote_Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
                {

                         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                         {
                                CharSequence strDate = null;
                                    Time chosenDate = new Time();        
                                    chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
                                    long dtDob = chosenDate.toMillis(true);

                                    strDate = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", dtDob);

                                    txtDate.setText(strDate);
                        }}, year,month,day);

                      dateDlg.show();
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

 public class MainClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy";
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
   try {
      Date date = format.parse("01-07-2013");
      System.out.println(date);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
 }
}
```

Hope its helpful.

You can also [refer to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display the date in 01-07-2013 MM-dd-yyyy format.

yes you can Do this by Below Steps.

> **Step 1:** you First have to Convert your String to Particular Date Format
>
> **Step 2:** Using SimpleDateFormat Convert your Date to MM-dd-yyyy format
>
> **Step 3:** Convert to String and Use it.

you can User Below Code for this.

```
 public class DateFormat {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Put here what your are getting as String
    String mytime="Jan 7, 2013"; 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MMM dd, yyyy"); //Step1: Convert yout String to perticular Date Formate according to your Date String your are getting
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Step2
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate); 
    //Step3: Here you will get your Final Date. Set your String now to textview.
       }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> ```
> private int m_month, m_year, m_day;
>  SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy",
>             Locale.ENGLISH);
>  m_month = m_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
>  m_year = m_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
>  m_day = m_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>  //for the datepicker listener.
>  m_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, p_year);
>  m_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, p_monthOfYear);
>  m_calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, p_dayOfMonth);
>  String m_sDate = dateParser.format(m_calendar.getTime()).toString();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following in my project. It might help you. Ask if you have any query.

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date originalDate = new Date();   //it will give today's date.
    String dateString = sdf.format(originalDate);
    Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(dateString);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        CharSequence formatted = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", mDueDate);
        mDueDateView.setText(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with if else statement may help :

```
//date picker code
date_c_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
date_c_input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
    
final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

// date picker dialog
picker = new DatePickerDialog(AddActivity_C.this,
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
String month_s="00";
String day_s="00";
monthOfYear= monthOfYear+ 1;
if(dayOfMonth < 10){

        day_s  = "0" + dayOfMonth ;
    }else {
        day_s=Integer.toString(dayOfMonth);
    }
if(monthOfYear < 10){

        month_s = "0" + monthOfYear;
    }else{
        month_s=Integer.toString(monthOfYear);
    }
date_c_input.setText(year+"-"+month_s+"-"+day_s);   
}
}, year, month, day);
picker.show();
}
}); 
//end of date code
```