# I want to change DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm an android developer.
I want to use DatePickerDialog.
But this widget is showing Year - Month.
I want to show Month - Year.
How?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190968/android-format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-from-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It works on  `>= 11`

If you need to customise your picker as per your requirement then better to create your own using NumberPickers, Here is the example -

```
public class MonthYearPickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

  private static final int MAX_YEAR = 2099;
  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

  public void setListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_dialog, null);
    final NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_month);
    final NumberPicker yearPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_year);

    monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
    monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
    monthPicker.setValue(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    yearPicker.setMinValue(year);
    yearPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_YEAR);
    yearPicker.setValue(year);

    builder.setView(dialog)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            listener.onDateSet(null, yearPicker.getValue(), monthPicker.getValue(), 0);
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MonthYearPickerDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
          }
        });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

Layout -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/picker_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        </NumberPicker>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/picker_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </NumberPicker>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

To show the dialogue box -

```
MonthYearPickerDialog pd = new MonthYearPickerDialog();
pd.setListener(this);
pd.show(getFragmentManager(), "MonthYearPickerDialog");
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653048/1741586

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks your answer. But I want also order -> Year - Month (X) to Month - Year (O)